# Taylor series for $\arctan x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

We use

$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$, where $|x|<1$

and integration yields

$\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

And by the ratio test this series converges for $|x|\le 1$. My question is how is it that the interval of convergence is bigger than above? Shouldn't we restrict it to  $|x|<1$ since the above formula for the sum of geometric series will not be valid for $x=1$ or $x=-1$?

Comment: Not really answering the question, but how exactly do you apply the ratio test here? (I have some trouble believing that for $x=i$, for instance, the series will converge.)

Comment: @ClementC. In its simplest form (for real n and x) the ratio test is just $\lim_{n \to \infty} |S(n+1, x)/S(n, x)| < 1 $, where S is the series in question. You then have to manually check the endpoints, as the ratio test says nothing about them - they may or may not converge. In applying the ratio test here the OP is excluding complex $x$ with non-zero imaginary part,  or so it appears

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, $\arctan(i)=i\infty$, so the series would not converge.  Perhaps, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, which is likely since the OP mentions an interval of convergence.  ;-))

Comment: That's how i understood it: the ratio test does **not** gives convergence for $|x|\leq1$. It gives it for $|x|<1$, and then 1 and -1 are dealt with separately. (Note that the ratio test would otherwise give convergence for all complex numbers with norm 1 as well, it does not discriminate. ..)